# Jquery - Get the text of multiple spans with the same class?

Tags: jquery

I'm relatively new to jquery, so I have what I hope will be a simple question.
I need to append multiple spans to the line items in an unordered list.
Essentially, each line item contains a  and I need to grab the content of that span and append it to the bottom of the line item it's contained in.  Here's what I have so far:

**My jquery code:**

```
$("ul").ready(function () {
    var Name = $(".name").text();
    var Content = $(".content").text();
    $("li").append("<span class=\"additional\"><a href=\"/addinfo.php\">" + Name + "'s additional info</a></span>");
});
```

**The original HTML it needs to modify:**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span class="name">John Doe</span><br />
        <span class="content">John is an excellent Swimmer</span><br />
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="name">Jane Doe</span><br />
        <span class="content">Jane loves to play basketball</span><br />
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Here's the output I'm getting:**

- John Doe
  John is an excellent Swimmer
  John DoeJane Doe's additional info
- Jane Doe
   
  Jane loves to play basketball
  John DoeJane Doe'sadditional info

**Here's the desired outcome:**

- John Doe
   
  John is an excellent Swimmer
  John Doe's additional info
- Jane Doe 
  Jane loves to play basketball 
  Jane Doe's additional info

As you can see, instead of taking the all the "Name" var's and putting them together, instead of just using the "Name" var of that line item.
I'm sure it needs some type of this, $(this), or .each call on it, but I can't seem to find this in the documentation anywhere.

Can someone help?
Thanks!
Troy

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
$("ul > li").each(function() {
    var Name = $(".name", this) .text();
    var Content = $(".content", this) .text();
    $(this).append("<span class=\"additional\"><a href=\"/addinfo.php\">"+ Name +"'s additional info</a></span>");
});
```

This will loop through each LI in the UL list and treat them as individual entities.  You had two major problems.  One is that you were not limiting the context of your jQuery selection so you were getting both ".name" classes and combining them together, that is why you got both names.  And then you were adding the values to all LI objects.

Comment: On the .append line, do you want to refer to it as $(this) instead of $("li") ?

Comment: great_llama inside the function() `this` will refer to the `li` element

Comment: Nope, this this didn't work... either with the $(this) or $("li")

Comment: actually... this did work, I accidentally removed the .ready call above it when copy and pasting.  thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

It's right here: http://docs.jquery.com/Core/each#callback

I would assign a class to all LI elements and then

```
$(".li-class").each(function(){
    var Name = $(".name", this) .text();
    var Content = $(".content", this) .text();
    $(this) .append("<span class=\"additional\"><a href=\"/addinfo.php\">"+ Name +"'s additional info</a></span>");
});
```

Comment: Actually, I did get this working as well... I replaced this with $(this) on the last line of code.