# Get the value of multiple spans

Tags: jquery, html

im starting with programming and got a problem i cant solve. How can i get the value of multiple spans with the same class?

HTML looks like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="300" />
        <label>
          At vero consecur <span class="price">300</span>
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="450" />
        <label>
          lorem ipsum <span class="price">450</span>
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="850" />
        <label>
          solor sit amet <span class="price">850</span>
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>Total Sum <span class="price">0</span></li>
</ul>
```

Now i want to get the value of the (.price) spans. With my code i get the value of every price span.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var preis = $('.price').text()
    var newprice = parseInt(preis)
    alert(newprice)
});
```

I tried something like this. But it doesnt work either.

```
$("ul li label span").each(function(index) {
    alert(index + ": " + $(".price").text());
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the price as related to the nearest `input`? If so you need to use DOM traversal instead of an `each` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `this` instead of `.price` in your `each`, because `.price` referencing all `span` with class `price`.

```
$( "ul li label span" ).each(function( index ) {
    alert( index + ": " + $(this).text() );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(this)` instead of `$(".price")`

**[Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/peyarunuqe/1/edit?html,css,js,output)**

```
$( "ul li label span" ).each(function( index ) {
      alert( index + ": " + $(this).text() );
});
```

You can use class directly if the class is not used in other part of the page.

**[Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/nufavejadu/edit?html,css,js,output)**

```
$('.price').each(function( index ) {
      alert( index + ": " + $(this).text() );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [each](http://api.jquery.com/each) and get the text using `$(this)` to refer to the corresponding element:

Ex-

```
$('.price').each(function(index,element){
   alert($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should apply jQuery [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) function to items with `price` class.

```
$(function() {
    $(".price").each(function(i, v) {
        console.log($(v).text());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop on each `.price`

```
var prices = new Array();

$(".price").each(function(key, val){
   var price = $(this).text();
   prices.push(price);
   alert(price);
});
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j9v886qz/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("ul > li").each(function() {
   var Name = $("label", this) .text();
   var price = $(".price", this) .text();
 ::::::::::::::
  ::::::
alert("");
 });
```

Might be [Jquery - Get the text of multiple spans with the same class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859910/jquery-get-the-text-of-multiple-spans-with-the-same-class) could help you...

Answer (score 0):

Grabbing the text inside `.price` is not really what you want to be doing here. I see that you want the values from all the checkboxes, then I'm guessing you want to calculate them.
You would be better off looping through the `<input>`'s and taking the value from there. This way, then you won't pick up a value of `0` for the last `.price` element.

I personally would go about it like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('input').each(function() {
        console.log($(this).val());
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop through the .price element.

```
$(".price").each(function(i){
    price = $(this).html()
    if (!isNaN(price)) total += Number(price);
});
```